# Instrumented tests can't run in Android library modules that have Kotlin files

Tags: android, testing, gradle, kotlin

It's basically in the title, I can't run any instrumented tests in Android library modules that contain Kotlin classes. This is regardless of whether the tests depend on the Kotlin classes.

Here are the simplest steps I could reproduce this issue with:

1. Create a new Android library project with default settings

   - Just to check, run example instrumented test, runs fine
   - Add a Kotlin class
   - Run example instrumented test, still runs fine
2. Add a new Android library module with all default settings again
3. Run example instrumented test, works fine
4. Add a Kotlin file, only containing a `class Something`
5. Attempt to run instrumented test again,  now the build fails with the following message:

   `Error:Execution failed for task ':mylibrary:transformClassesWithDexForDebugAndroidTest'.`

   `> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lco/zsmb/example/mylibrary/Something;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [known issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16854) of Kotlin Gradle plugin 1.1.1. It was not present in version 1.1.0, and it has already been fixed for [1.1.2 EAP](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-1-1-2-eap/2457), please try one of these versions.

Comment: This was precisely my issue, I can't believe I couldn't find it through Google. I upgraded to the EAP, works like a charm. Thank you!